# Should we edit titles for clarity when a question relates to a specific add-on?

Tags: discussion

Take this question as an example;

[How can I increase the number of custom Order Fields in Expresso Store?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/9504/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-custom-order-fields)

The question relates very specifically to Espresso:Store.

I know there is a tag showing that it's an Espresso:Store question but should we edit the title to include the add on name since it is such a specific question?

In this case I would say the title should be something like

**"How can I increase the number of custom Order Fields in Espresso:Store?"**

To me it just seems that for the sake of clarity the question title should contain specifics like this.

Answer (score 5):

I agree, and edit titles in this manner often.

Comment: I edit titles too as needed to make the questions more clear. Edit away!

Comment: I would agree - if you're having issues with a particular add-on, having that in the title would definitely help you sift results.

Comment: Plus - the page and title will be pulled into search results that get served up to a wider audience, and ppl might be drawn here when they either didn't know about this place (which is how I first found stackoverflow) or they may decide that this question is better suited than something similar on another site, to what they also want to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Agree, this is really helpful to have the specific add-on in the title, because often people don't look at the tags and just give a generic answer.